# what does "overlapping" of orbitals mean and why does it effect bond strength(VBT)?

Tags: bond, valence-bond-theory

according to valence bond theory, bonds are formed due to the pairing of unpaired valence electrons due to the overlap of half-filled orbitals, and the strength of the bond depends on the extent of overlap.

the concept of "overlapping" sounds visually intuitive and a good qualitative explanation, but the dependence of the strength of the bond on the extent of overlap implies there is a quantitative framework behind this.

Orbitals, as far as I understand, are just physical representations of the 3d probability distribution of finding an electron in a given region given by modulus-squared of its wavefunction. So what does it actually mean when atomic orbitals "overlap"? Secondly, what exactly is the extent of overlap and why does it affect bond strength?

Comment: You might search for S the Overlap Integral.

Comment: Overlap -> constructive interference. VBT is not a good place to start for this.